# Android Java Array indexoutofbound

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

how do i make a button go to the last place in an array when pressed without getting an indexoutofbound error?

```
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.back:
        mainButton.setText(alphabet[position--]);
        mainButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(randomColor, randomColor2, randomColor3));
        if (alphabet.equals("A")) {
            mainButton.setText(alphabet[25]);
        }

        break;
    case R.id.forward:
        mainButton.setText(alphabet[position++]);
        mainButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(randomColor, randomColor2, randomColor3));

        if (alphabet.equals("Z")) {
            mainButton.setText(alphabet[0]);
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: what is the size of alphabet array ??

Comment: A-Z... it is 26 @Youngistan

Comment: 25 is last position alphabet[25]

Comment: if your array-size is 26 and you are looking for the 27th element, then you get index out of bounds exception

Comment: if (alphabet.equals...)?? it's an array, not a string. **if(alphabet[position].equals...)**. AND you have the position issue.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo array also have equals method

Comment: Use a variable (such as "position"). Increase or decrease IT. Make comparisons to see whether it is inside the bounds (0, ..., 25). If greater then 25, set it to 0. If lower than 0, set it to 25. Only after, mainButton's text to the value of alphabet[position] (and its background color to a randomic color). The algorithm is ready.

Comment: @Youngistan: YES... IF YOU ARE COMPARING TWO ARRAYS. Not an array and a string! These aren't comparabe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, if get what you are trying to do.
First calculate the position of the array so as to be inside the bounds. Then access the array position.

```
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.back:
    position--;
    if(position<0) { position=25; }
    // mainButton.setText(alphabet[position]);
    // mainButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(randomColor, randomColor2, randomColor3));

    break;
case R.id.forward:
    position++;
    if(position>25) { position=0; }
    // mainButton.setText(alphabet[position]);
    // mainButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(randomColor, randomColor2, randomColor3));

    break;
}
// for better improvement this can be added once for both cases
mainButton.setText(alphabet[position]);
mainButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(randomColor, randomColor2, randomColor3));
```

This check `alphabet.equals("A"))` has no actual meaning as you are trying to compare an array with a string value this will always return you false.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and get the value from the last index in the array you can just use this

```
alphabet[alphabet.length-1]);
```

Using `arrayname.length-1` instead of a specific index number will always return the last index even if your array has changed size. Although I believe there is more wrong with your code than just the index out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

shorter solution even someone got the green tick :(

```
{//your method...
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.back:
            position--;
            position = modulo(position, alphabet.length);
            mainButton.setText(alphabet[position]);
            mainButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(randomColor, randomColor2, randomColor3));

            break;
        case R.id.forward:
            position++;
            position = modulo(position, alphabet.length);
            mainButton.setText(alphabet[position]);
            mainButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(randomColor, randomColor2, randomColor3));

            break;
    }
}

private int modulo(int x, int y) {
    return (int) (x - (y * Math.floor((double) x / (double) y)));
}
```

So when you get `-1`, `position` will change to `alphabet.length-1`
when you get `alphabet.length+1` your position will change to `0`